# Solving recurrence using EGF

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

How do I solve the recurrence relation $a_n = na_{n - 1}+ (n - 1)!$ using exponential generating function?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to MSE!

Let $A = \sum \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n$ be the exponential generating function of $a_n$.

Dividing both sides of the recurrence by $n!$ gives

$$
\frac{a_n}{n!} 
= \frac{na_{n-1}}{n!} + \frac{(n-1)!}{n!} 
= \frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + \frac{1}{n}
$$

Then if we multiply both sides by $x^n$ we get

$$
\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n = \frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}x^n + \frac{1}{n}x^n
$$

and summing over all $n \geq 1$ (being careful of the $a_0$ boundary term) gives

$$
A - a_0 = xA + \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n} x^n
$$

We can solve this for $A$:

$$
A = \frac{1}{1-x} \left ( a_0 + \sum \frac{1}{n} x^n \right )
$$

But we know the $x^n$ coefficient of $\frac{a_0}{1-x}$: it's exactly $a_0$.

We *also* know the $x^n$ coefficeint of $\frac{1}{1-x} \sum \frac{1}{n} x^n$, at least in theory. It turns out that

$$\frac{1}{1-x} \sum_{n \geq 0} c_n x^n = \sum_{n \geq 0} \left ( \sum_{0 \leq k \leq n} c_k \right ) x^n$$

that is, the $x^n$ coefficient is exactly the $n$th partial sum of the original series. You can see this mentioned [here](http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi2/section-27.html) or in the excellent book [generatingfunctionology](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfology2.pdf) (rule 5 on page $37$).

So then by comparing coefficients on both sides, we find

$$\frac{a_n}{n!} = a_0 + \sum_{k \leq n} \frac{1}{n}$$

In other words,

$$a_n = n! (a_0 + H_n)$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$th [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

In case you're feeling doubtful, it's easy to ask
[sage](https://sagemath.org) to double check that this is true.
Here I've set $a_0 = 1$:

[image: a quick verification]

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: However I didn't get any constant like $a_0$. I only got the coefficient to be $H_n$. Is something wrong?

Comment: Any closed form of a recurrence relation _must_ depend on the initial value (unless you're only interested in asymptotics), so you probably made a minor error. My guess is that the computation you did was silently assuming $a_0 = 0$, which is a very easy mistake to make, and a potentially hard mistake to catch

Comment: Ah I see. Got it. Thanks. I highly appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: Happy to help ^_^. If this answered your question, you should mark it as such. That way other users know where to spend their time. Of course, you're welcome to leave it open for a day or two to see if anyone else wants to chime in.

Comment: Also is this the only way to solve this recurrence using EGF?

Comment: It's hard to answer those kinds of questions. At the very least it's the most _natural_ way. If you thought really hard you might be able to come up with another way, but I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: Also what do you mean by asymptotics?

Comment: Oftentimes you don't care (or can't figure out) a perfect closed form formula for $a_n$. Instead, you find an expression which _approximates_ $a_n$ (say, to within a constant multiple). If you only want an approximation, then the particular choice of $a_0$ often doesn't matter.

Comment: Arguably, the recurrence is solvable by inspection. Consider the substitution $b_n:=a_n/n!$. Then the recurrence becomes $b_n=b_{n-1}+1/n$, and therefore $$b_n = b_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}=b_{n-2}+\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}=\cdots = b_0+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=b_0+H_n.$$ That's of course equivalent to the EGF solution.